# Formula to return time difference but not display 0

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets with start (C) and end (D) timestamps. I am calculating the time difference using `=(D1-C1)`. I have copied the formula to empty columns which returns a 0 time difference.

Is there a way to hide the value if it returns 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula will do just that:

```
=IF(D1-C1=0;"";D1-C1)
```

It says: if the result of D1-C1 equals 0, then show nothing (""), else show the result.

Comment: Thanks. I extended the formula to `=IF(D1>0;IF(D1-C1=0;"";D1-C1);"")` so that it will only display a difference if the End time stamp has a value.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding `0` may be easier with formatting:

```
[=0];[HH]:mm:ss
```

Or you might consider a further step, which would be to blank out where you have a `C` value but not (yet?) a `D` one:

```
[HH]:mm:ss;;
```

In both cases where a result is shown it is displayed as hours:minutes:seconds (but may be adjusted).